# Why isn't JMSExpiration, JMSPriority set when sending a message to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue via JMS?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm sending a message to a queue with a priority of 7 and a lifetime of 600000 ms. And I do not understand why a message with a priority of 4 and a lifetime of never falls into the queue

Message sending class:

```java
public class SendMessageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueueConnection connection = null;
        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        try {
            initialContext = new InitialContext();
            QueueConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
            Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("dynamicQueues/" + "exampleQueue");
            connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
            QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is a text message");
            message.setJMSCorrelationID("3445125584339");
            message.setJMSReplyTo(queue);
            message.setJMSPriority(7);
            message.setJMSExpiration(600000);
            System.out.println("Sent message: " + message.getText());
            producer.send(message);

        } catch (NamingException | JMSException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The message that arrives in the queue:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the JMS API incorrectly. As noted in the JavaDoc both `setJMSPriority` and `setJMSExpiration` **cannot** be used by the client application. These are only to be used by the JMS provider itself. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSPriority-int-) for priority:

> This method is for use by **JMS providers only** to set this field when a message is sent. This message **cannot be used by clients** to configure the priority level of the message. This method is public to allow a JMS provider to set this field when sending a message whose implementation is not its own.

And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSExpiration-long-) for expiration:

> This method is for use by **JMS providers only** to set this field when a message is sent. This message **cannot be used by clients** to configure the expiration time of the message. This method is public to allow a JMS provider to set this field when sending a message whose implementation is not its own.

You can use the [`setPriority(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setPriority-int-) and [`setTimeToLive(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setTimeToLive-long-) methods of `MessageProducer` instead, e.g.:

```java
public class SendMessageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueueConnection connection = null;
        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        try {
            initialContext = new InitialContext();
            QueueConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
            Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("dynamicQueues/" + "exampleQueue");
            connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
            QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            producer.setPriority(7);
            producer.setTimeToLive(600000);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is a text message");
            message.setJMSCorrelationID("3445125584339");
            message.setJMSReplyTo(queue);
            producer.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message: " + message.getText());
        } catch (NamingException | JMSException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```